# Find and Move in a singly linked list

Tags: c

I keep getting an error in my code and cannot figure out what is wrong.
The code is supposed to find the first node that contains the findValue and move the node from its current location to the head of the list.

Following is the error message I receive -

```
list.c:56:15: error: invalid operands to binary expression
('int (*)()' and 'int')
count << node->value << " ";
```

The function:

```
void findAndMove(listNode **listPtr, int findValue) {  
  if (*listPtr == NULL || (*listPtr)->next == NULL)  
    return;  

  listNode *secLast = NULL;  
  listNode *last = *listPtr;  

  while (last->next != NULL)  
  {
      if(last->value == findValue)
      {
        break;
      }
      secLast = last;  
      last = last->next;  
  }  

  secLast->next = last->next;  

  last->next = *listPtr;  

  *listPtr = last;  
}  

void push(listNode** head_ref, int new_data)  
{  
    listNode* new_node = new_listNode(); 

    new_node->value = new_data;  

    new_node->next = (*head_ref);  

    (*head_ref) = new_node;  
}  

void printList(listNode *node)  
{  
    while(node != NULL)  
    {  
        count << node->value << " ";  
        node = node->next;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing? count << node->value << " ";  It looks like it would be compiled out

Comment: i think your trying to print, but you need printf in C, theres no cout if thats what you were trying to do

Comment: Additionally, `count <<` wouldn't do it in C++ (probably a typo for `cout <<`) -- which won't work in C. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
void printList(listNode *node)  
{  
    while(node != NULL)  
    {  
        count << node->value << " ";  
        node = node->next;  
    }  
}
```

This line with `count << node->value << " ";`  looks like your trying to use cout, from C++'s standard namespace.  In C you need to use printf like the one below:

```
void printList(listNode *node)  
{  
    while(node != NULL)  
    {  
        //count << node->value << " ";  
        printf("%d \n", node->value); //IDK what the print should be because you didnt post the node struct, but you need to use a function from the printf family if your printing 
        node = node->next;  
    }  
}
```

*EDIT* When i first read your question i thought you were doing some bit shifting, until i read the function name to try to determine what you were trying to do.  I assumed the shifts with " " would be shifting 32 bits, then shifting node->value, on some int count, which never gets assigned and thus it would get optimized out.

Comment: why did i get a thumbs down for this?  it was accepted.  Atleast leave a note when you give a thumbs down...